# AWS JAVA IoT client reconnections and timeouts

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot, disconnect

I use IoT Rules on CONNECTED/DISCONNECTED topic (from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-lambda-rule.html)). So I want to get email when a device is connected or disconnected. On my device I run next code on startup (only on startup):

```
iotClient = new AWSIotMqttClient(Configuration.IOT_CLIENT_ENDPOINT,
                    deviceId,
                    keyStore,
                    keystorePass);
            
iotClient.setKeepAliveInterval(1200000); //20 minutes (maximum)
iotClient.connect();
```

But I get very strange behavior. I have 3 devices, and on each device I get this stacktrace but due to different reasons:

```
[pool-8-thread-1] com.amazonaws.services.iot.client.core.AwsIotConnection.onConnectionSuccess Connection successfully established
[pool-8-thread-1] com.amazonaws.services.iot.client.core.AbstractAwsIotClient.onConnectionSuccess Client connection active: <client ID>
[pool-8-thread-1] com.amazonaws.services.iot.client.core.AwsIotConnection.onConnectionFailure Connection temporarily lost
[pool-8-thread-1] com.amazonaws.services.iot.client.core.AbstractAwsIotClient.onConnectionFailure Client connection lost: <client ID>
[pool-8-thread-1] com.amazonaws.services.iot.client.core.AwsIotConnection$1.run Connection is being retried
[pool-8-thread-1] com.amazonaws.services.iot.client.core.AwsIotConnection.onConnectionSuccess Connection successfully established
[pool-8-thread-1] com.amazonaws.services.iot.client.core.AbstractAwsIotClient.onConnectionSuccess Client connection active: <client ID>
```

Sometimes I get this stacktrace due to DUPLICATE_CLIENTID disconnection reason, or sometimes due to MQTT_KEEP_ALIVE_TIMEOUT disconnection reason (MQTT_KEEP_ALIVE_TIMEOUT happens every 30-35 minutes, DUPLICATE_CLIENTID happens every 10 minutes)

So, I don't understand why do I need to deal with DUPLICATE_CLIENTID if **each client has a unique ID**, and to deal with MQTT_KEEP_ALIVE_TIMEOUT if **there no an intermittent connectivity issue** (I get logs every minute to my server, so it isn't WIFI/internet issue). I use the latest AWS IoT SDK from here - https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-java.

How can I solve these issues?

**MY TRICKY SOLUTION:**

I added a scheduled thread that sends empty messages to topic - ${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/ping every 20 minutes:

```
scheduledExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
    try {
        iotClient.publish(String.format(Configuration.PING_TOPIC, deviceId), AWSIotQos.QOS0, "");
    } catch (AWSIotException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Failed to send ping", e);
    }
}, Configuration.PING_INITIAL_DELAY_IN_MINUTES, Configuration.PING_PERIOD_IN_MINUTES, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

So this solution solves inactive issue, but I still want to find a more elegant solution...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your logs, it definitly seems like it is connection lost, then connection retried.

During reconnection, it is still connecting using the deviceID you are passing, (however the connection might not have existed from MQTT side), and therefore it sees that it is trying to connect with the same id.

Reading a bit about this, looks like you might not be actually registering your device as a (thing) in aws..

If you were, they when you create an MQTT connection and pass that thingId, then even on reconnection, it wont give you that DuplicateID error.

```
     AWSIotMqttClient client = new AWSIotMqttClient(...);
     
     SomeDevice someDevice = new SomeDevice(thingName);    // SomeDevice extends AWSIotDevice
     
     client.attach(someDevice);
     
     client.connect();
```

you can also experiment with `iotClient.cleanSession(true/false)` to see if that can help you.

> /**
> * Sets whether the client and server should establish a clean session on each connection.
> * If false, the server should attempt to persist the client's state between connections.
> * This must be set before {@link #connect()} is called.
> *
> * @param cleanSession
> *            If true, the server starts a clean session with the client on each connection.
> *            If false, the server should persist the client's state between connections.
> */

```
@Override
public void setCleanSession(boolean cleanSession) { super.setCleanSession(cleanSession); }
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-thing-management.html

> MQTT_KEEP_ALIVE_TIMEOUT   If there is no client-server communication
> for 1.5x of the client's keep-alive time, the client is disconnected.

That means you are not sending/receiving messages..there is no way to fix that, unless you keep an active connection and do things

Comment: So, if a device is UP, but not sending/receiving messages, then every 30 minutes I'll get emails about connection/disconnection status? It looks weird. How can I solve it with using AWS IoT?

Comment: @Rougher that is what the documentation states...The clients disconnects if no activity.

Comment: But what about iotClient.setKeepAliveInterval(0)? Setting this value to 0 will disable the keep-alive function for the connection. Read here: https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-iot-device-sdk-java/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/iot/client/AWSIotMqttClient.java

Comment: Try it @Rougher.  Maybe 0 keep it alive forever?  It is worth a try.  Please update me.  I would love to know

Comment: If I set keep-alive to 0, after 30 minutes it disconnects and doesn't reconnect. It looks like this issue: https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js/issues/254